# How to disable go to next search result with Cmd+F in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Something seems to have changed recently with Chrome in how Cmd+F works.

To reproduce:

**Before**:

1. Cmd+F opens search box.
2. Perform a search (i.e. "stack")
3. Doing Cmd+F again would do nothing other than focusing the search box.

**Now**:

1. Cmd+F opens search box.
2. Perform a search (i.e. "stack")
3. Doing Cmd+F again navigates you to the next search result.

I'm finding this really annoying – out of habit, I usually just do Cmd+F to make sure the search box is focused before I change the text in it, and this causes jumps around the page due to it

---

Demo of the issue:

[image]

All I am doing in that video is pressing `Command+F` over and over after doing a search.

Comment: Doesn't happen on Windows using Ctrl-F. Maybe try Chrome in Incognito mode to disable all extensions.

Comment: It's not from an extension, pretty sure it's just from how Chrome now behaves macOS. I've updated my question with a gif.

Comment: You can't do anything about that.  This is a bug or feature.  You would need to send a patch to chromium code.

Comment: I repeat that on Windows it works as you wish it, the focus stays in the search window and I can search next by pressing Enter. Perhaps completely scrubbing Chrome from the disk and re-install may help.

Comment: This "feature" is annoying. For years, if the search box was open and I wanted to close it, I would press Command+F, then Escape. Now I can no longer do this without the page jumping around.

Comment: This should now be fixed in the latest version of Chrome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug introduced in version 78.0.3869.0 of Chrome for Mac

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1043550#c3

Comment: Glad to hear that this is a bug and not a new "feature"

Comment: Just updated to `Version 84.0.4147.89` and it looks like its been fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded to Chrome 84 and it seems this bug has been fixed. Finally...